# Why is fgets() being skipped in loop?

Tags: c, loops, buffer, fgets

I'm iterating through a loop. On the first iteration, i can write on the stdin and get the data I want. on the second operation: name is skipped, and it asks me for name2. Why is it skipping name?

```
   for (i = 0; TRUE; i++) {
        printf("> nom :");
        fgets(items[i].name, 15, stdin);
        printf("nom: %s\n", items[i].name);
        if (items[i].name[0] == '.') break;

        printf("> prenom : ");
        fgets(items[i].name2, 15, stdin);
        printf("name2: %s\n", items[i].name2);
    }
```

Comment: `printf("stdin: %s\n", stdin);` --> `stdin` is a `FILE *`, not a `char *`

Comment: Yes, true I added this just for random testing. not getting any solution. Any idea what could be the problem @AlterMann

Comment: Did you happen to call `scanf()` earlier? This is a common symptom when mixing line-oriented and field-oriented input where you end up with an extra `\n` sitting waiting for you on `stdin`.

Comment: No idea, show us a complete and compilable code

Comment: @FatalError I'm doing this exercise for lab at university. We have to use fgets() to avoid buffer overflow. I tried using:
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
to empty the stdin but it isn't working

Comment: @AlterMann the code is part of a big problem
I have a structure ITEM (char[20] name, char[30] lastname)
I'm filling an array of ITEM by reading through the stdin. It works with scanf, but the teacher wants us to use fgets

Comment: @FatalError and AlterMann: thanks guys, I am using scanf in the loop after fgets, so I have to empty the stdin just after the scanf now it is working

Comment: If you want to get good answers and to avoid wasting our time, then post code that actually fails for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented does not prompt for the `name`, even on the first iteration of the loop. If you get any prompting for it at all then that is happening before entering the loop. In contrast, the code presented does prompt for `name2`.

Each iteration of the loop begins by reading the next `name` (without prompting) and printing it. If you see different behavior then you are running different code.

Comment: Yes, that's not all what's in the loop. I am using a scanf after my fgets, so I emptied the buffer and it's working now. thank you